# Can $n$ hyperplanes separate any $\sum_{k = 0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}$ points in $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: combinatorics

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409518/how-many-resulting-regions-if-we-partition-mathbbrm-with-n-hyperplanes?answertab=votes#tab-top), we know that $n$ planes will partition $\mathbb{R}^m$ into a maximum of $N_{m,n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}$ regions. Now we ask the reverse: given any $N_{m,n}$ points in general position in $\mathbb{R}^m$ do **there always exist** $n$ hyperplanes that will separate these points?

E.g. with $N_{2,3} = 7$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the hypothesis is that there always exist $n = 3$ lines that completely separate any $7$ points.

[image]

Comment: if 7 points are colinear then you need 6 lines to separate them...

Comment: Whoops - thanks guys. Fixed question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a regular heptagon?  Each line has to separate the points into a group of three and a group of four.  Two lines will give one isolated point and two pairs.  But I can't find a third line to split all three pairs.