# Prove that the $n$th term of a sequence whose $(m-1)$th differences are $1,2,...$ is the number of regions in $\mathbb{R}^m$ made by $n-1$ hyperplanes

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

> **Conjecture:** Let $A(m,n)$ denote the number of regions in $\mathbb{R}^m$ formed by $n$ hyperplanes and $T_{m,n}$ denote the $n$th term of a sequence whose $(m-1)$th differences are $1,2,3,4,5,...$. It then holds that $T_{m,n} = A(m, n-1)$.

My question is motivated by my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4446005/1044958) question where I show that if the above conjecture is true, then $T_{m,k} = \sum_{k=0}^{m} {n-1 \choose k} \tag{1}$

It follows that the converse is true i.e. $(1) \implies$ the above conjecture is true. The user [QC_QAOA](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/364346/qc-qaoa) has now proven $(1)$ which proves the above conjecture. However, I would like to know a way to prove directly that $T_{m,n} = A(m, n-1)$ without having to prove $(1)$.

My attempt was as follows (quoted from my original answer):

> Note that $$A(m, n) = A(m, n-1) + A(m-1, n-1) \iff A(m,n) - A(m, n-1) = A(m-1, n-1)$$
>
> *(Proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973761/1044958))*
>
> If Claim $1$ is true, it follows that $$T_{m, n} = A(m, n-1) \implies T_{m, n+1} = A(m, n)$$ $$T_{m, n+1} - T_{m, n} = A(m, n) - A(m, n-1) = A(m-1, n-1) \tag{1}$$
>
> I have been unable to prove $(1)$, i.e. the difference between the
> $(n+1)$th and $n$th terms of a sequence whose $(m-1)$th differences are $1,2,3,4,5...$
> is the same as the number of regions formed by $n-1$ hyperplanes in
> $\mathbb{R}^{m-1}$. If someone is able to demonstrate this, however,
> the proof is complete.

Hence, I was able to transform the problem into proving $T_{m, n+1} - T_{m, n} = A(m-1, n-1)$. However, I am not sure how to take this forward.

Comment: Reminds me of this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0gbw-Ur_do

Comment: @Aplateofmomos Thanks for sharing - I'll take a look!

Comment: You may want to skip like 8 mins ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973761/429987) has exactly what you need. They show the formula
$$A(m,n) = A(m, n-1) + A(m-1, n-1)$$
By considering removing and adding a hyperplane, in particular noting that the number of regions added will be the number of regions the other hyperplanes form on the new hyperplane.

Thus, writing $A(m,n) = A(m)(n)$we get that
$$\Delta [A(m)](n) =A(m)(n+1)-A(m)(n) = A(m-1)(n)$$
And so by induction
$$\Delta^{m-1}[A(m)](n) = A(1)(n) = n+1$$
which is how you've defined $T_{m,n+1}$, so we're done.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I had all these little pieces of information floating around in my head but I couldn’t make that final push. That notation $-$ $\Delta^{m-1}$ $-$ is a game-changer.