# Recurrence problem about planes

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the recurrence relation satisfied by Sn, where Sn is the number of regions into which three dimensional space is divided by n planes if every three of the planes meet in one point, but no four of the planes go through the same point.
I figured out that the nth plane should go through every two from the set of n-1 planes, however, I don't get how many regions that adds. It's difficult to visualise this.

Comment: @JeanMarie The formula for $P_n$ there is not very revealing, it's nicer to write it as $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}$.

Comment: @Alexander Burstein You are right, as in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/409518/305862) by Calvin Lin and also Guojun Zhang

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, it looks like it does.